# Android volley Body in post request

Tags: java, android, post, http-post, android-volley

i dont found how i can configure a   body in my Post request, im using android studio

`

```
private RequestQueue mQueue;

private void send() {
    Log.i("start", "start");
    final String url1 = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/~/in-cse";

    JsonObjectRequest getRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url1, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Log.d("Response", response.toString());

                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.d("Error.Response", String.valueOf(error));
                }
            }
    ) {
        @Override
        public Map getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Log.i("rentrer dedans", "Headers");
            HashMap headers = new HashMap();
            headers.put("X-M2M-Origin", "admin:admin");
            headers.put("Accept", "application/xml");
            return headers;
        }
      @Override
        public Map<String,String> getParams(){
        Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("m2m:ae", "xmlns:m2m="http://www.onem2m.org/xml/protocols" rn="MY_SENSOR");
        params.put("api", "app-sensor");
        params.put("lbl", "Type/sensor Category/temperature Location/home");
        params.put("ff", "false");
        return params;
    }

    };
    // add it to the RequestQueue  
    mQueue.add(getRequest);
}
```

this is my code, and below there is my body, the thing is i dont know how to translate my body in my post request

`<m2m:ae xmlns:m2m="http://www.onem2m.org/xml/protocols" rn="MY_SENSOR" > <api>app-sensor</api> <lbl>Type/sensor Category/temperature Location/home</lbl> <rr>false</rr> </m2m:ae>`

Would appreciate some help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement things like this :-

```
    String var="xmlns:m2m=\"http://www.onem2m.org/xml/protocols\" rn=\"MY_SENSOR";
```

Here, '\' help you inserting more Double Quotes in String values.

Let me know, if anything i miss or you need more help.
Please like my answer if you find it useful.

Easy and more efficent way to post things using volley,

```
 JSONObject jsonObject= new JSONObject();
 try{
     jsonObject.put("m2m:ae", "xmlns:m2m=\"http://www.onem2m.org/xml/protocols\" rn=\"MY_SENSOR");
     jsonObject.put("api", "app-sensor");
     jsonObject.put("lbl", "Type/sensor Category/temperature Location/home");
    jsonObject.put("ff", "false");
    }catch(JSONException e){
    }
```

Or for More Better ways, There is an Library which i personally recommend to any android developer who love Light weight Volley for Api Integrations.

https://github.com/Lib-Jamun/Volley

```
dependencies {
  compile 'tk.jamun:volley:0.0.4'
}
```

Use this or updated version of this for more efficent use of Volley.

Check internet Connectivity :

```
public class CheckConnection {

  public static boolean checkConnection(Activity activity) {
    ConnectivityManager cm =
            (ConnectivityManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = null;
    if (cm != null) {
        activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (activeNetwork != null &&
                activeNetwork.isConnected()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            MySnackBar.getInstance().showSnackBarForMessage(activity, R.string.connection_check_no_internet);
        }
    }
    return false;
  }

public static boolean checkCon(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager cm =
            (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = null;
    if (cm != null) {
        activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetwork != null &&
                activeNetwork.isConnected();
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

then just need to code like

```
   If (CheckConnection.checkCon(this)){
       Call Volley;
   }else{
       Log.d("Tag","No internet");
   }
```

Let me know further responses

Comment: Thanks you for the answer, 
So i need to do that ?
        `String var = "xmlns:m2m=\"http://www.onem2m.org/xml/protocols\" rn=\"MY_SENSOR\" api=\"app-sensor\" lbl=\"Type/sensor Category/temperature Location/home \"rr=\"false"; `

And how do i use the var ?

Comment: Oh its not like you need to implement variable things, You can use them directly like,
  params.put("m2m:ae", "xmlns:m2m=\"http://www.onem2m.org/xml/protocols\" rn=\"MY_SENSOR");

Comment: Please see the updated answer where i am showing you another or easy and efficient way to post things using volley. Please vote my answer if you find this useful

Comment: thanks a lot,it really helped me 
 now im sending the request to my localhost using a emulator and i got this error  by any chance do you know how can i solve this?  
   `2019-02-24 11:57:11.329 20794-20794/com.example.myapplication D/Error.Response: com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to /127.0.0.1:8080 `

my URL is up and I can access it using postman

Comment: For Getting actual error first do some basic checks
1. Check you are asking Internet Permission in Manifest
2. Before Api Call You need to check internet connection (Showing in updated answer)

I am including Internet Checking Class and How to use method
Please let me know further responses

Comment: i fixed the internet error thanks ! i needed to change the url.
So now i did my post request and got this 

`2019-02-25 01:19:10.008 23220-23220/com.example.myapplication D/Error.Response: com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: Value <!-- of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject`

and i cant see why i got this

Comment: This means your API returning data is not in JSON format. First try to Log the response on console and fix this as per your need.